# Convert https to http in local WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I recently migrate my online website to localhost, And I am trying to access the homepage but it automatically uses HTTPS and it refuses to open, Although I disable SSL and the other pages are working just fine.

I deactivate my SSL plugin but nothing changed for the homepage especially.
I need to know what is the issue and how to fix it.
Thanks for listening folks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you can:

- If you can still access the admin, please try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) to search and replace all the HTTPS URLs with HTTP URLs.
- Please check your `wp-config.php` file if there is any defined site URL and replace it with HTTP if it has, like this instruction: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php
- Rename the `.htaccess` file if there is any redirection rules in this file applied for HTTPS. (You can re-save the setting in admin Settings > Permalink to re-generate the default WordPress `.htaccess`).